# How convert Gregorian date to Persian date?

Tags: c#, date, gregorian-calendar, date-conversion, persian

I want to convert a custom Gregorian date to Persian date in C#.
For example, i have a string with this contents:

```
string GregorianDate = "Thursday, October 24, 2013";
```

Now i want to have:

> string PersianDate = پنج‌شنبه 2 آبان 1392 ;

or

> string PersianDate = 1392/08/02

Thanks

Comment: To Help Persians I have Added some Library Here.  1. [PersianDateTime for .Net and .Net Core](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.PersianDateTime)  2. [Bootstrap PersianDateTimePicker](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the PersianCalendar:

```
string GregorianDate = "Thursday, October 24, 2013";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(GregorianDate);
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(d), pc.GetMonth(d), pc.GetDayOfMonth(d)));
```

Comment: The answer is for 7 years ago. So I put Here [link](https://github.com/Mds92), updated some libraries. There are PersianDateTime and PersianDateTimePicker for .NET and .NET Core. For all dear Persians.

Answer (score 8):

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 10, 24);
    var calendar = new PersianCalendar();
    var persianDate = new DateTime(calendar.GetYear(date), calendar.GetMonth(date), calendar.GetDayOfMonth(date));
    var result = persianDate.ToString("yyyy MMM ddd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-Ir"));
```

Comment: In windows 10, with persian culture as default, this code will not work

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi It works for me even in windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

You can use PersianDateTime:

```
PM> Install-Package PersianDateTime
```

The Reference: [PersianDateTime](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1349/persiandatetime-%D8%AC%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%B2%DB%8C%D9%86%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-system-datetime)

You can use `string.Split()` if you need customization.

Comment: Usage example always is nice to see in answers.

Comment: link is broken now

Answer (score 6):

The fowlling code should work in .net 4+ :

```
DateTime date=Convert.ToDateTime("2020-07-12T19:30:00.000Z");
string persianDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

`persianDateString` value would be:

```
1399/04/23
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding up to other answers, You can get the first one by using [PersianDateTime](http://persiandatetime.codeplex.com/):

```
var gregorianDate = "Thursday, October 24, 2013";
var date = DateTime.Parse(gregorianDate);
var persianDate = new PersianDateTime(date);
var result = persianDate.ToString("dddd d MMMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, using framework 4+:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("1392/08/02",new CultureInfo("fa-IR")));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1392/08/02", new CultureInfo("fa-IR")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `DateTime` to Iran time using this method:

```
DateTime timeInIran = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTimeToConvert, "Iran Standard Time" );
```