# GetDayOfWeek in specific calender(PersianCalender) in C#

Tags: c#

i want to get DayOfWeek in persianCalnder but it is always same as Georgian Calender,

```
       DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
       PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();

     var  geDayOfWeek= today.DayOfWeek;             
     var pcDayOfWeek=pc.GetDayOfWeek(today);
```

why the value of geDayOfWeek and pcDayOfWeek are always the same ? 
persian week starts in Saturday not Monday , so  for example Sunday should be 2 not 0 .

any solution to get day number in Persian calendar ?

i need this to calculate start date and end date  of week  in Persian Calendar not Georgian Calendar.

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683664/how-convert-gregorian-date-to-persian-date

Comment: no, i can get the date in persian calnder , but i cant get the day number in persian calender , for example if current day is sunday , the pc.GetDayOfWeek(today) should return 2 not 0 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a extention method for DateTime to get Persion Day Of Week

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static PersianDayOfWeek PersionDayOfWeek(this DateTime date)
    {
        switch (date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Shanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Yekshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Doshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Seshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Charshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Panjshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Jome;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    public enum PersianDayOfWeek
    {
        Shanbe=1,
        Yekshanbe=2,
        Doshanbe=3,
        Seshanbe=4,
        Charshanbe=5,
        Panjshanbe=6,
        Jome=7
    }
}
```

You can use it like this :

```
PersianDayOfWeek DoW = DateTime.Now.PersionDayOfWeek();
```

Comment: thanks arvin , so what is use of GetDayOfWeek in persian calender ?

Comment: @Arash with this method you will get if your date is Sunday, you will get `PersianDayOfWeek.Yekshanbe` which is 2 , as you want.

Comment: thanks . but microsoft should redesign persianCalenday , what is point of GetDayOfWeek in this calender.

Answer (score 3):

Reason for behavior you see is that return value of `Calendar.GetDayOfWeek` is enum ie. constant - Sunday is always 0 independently from the Calendar you use. In other words returned value does not reflect which day is considered "start of the week" in specific calendar...