# How to convert datetime in views for items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am going to convert Georgian date time to Persian in display views. I used a function to this in view body, a method in core class, neither worked. How to use a function to convert the date?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRegistered)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use [DisplayFormat] annotation?

Comment: does this answer your question? ==>  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683664/how-convert-gregorian-date-to-persian-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I have added a `[NotMapped]` property to the class like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "تاریخ ثبت")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string PersianDate => GetPersianDate();
    public string GetPersianDate()
    {
        System.Globalization.PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
        return string.Join("/", new string[] {
            persianCalendar.GetYear(DateRegistered).ToString(),
            persianCalendar.GetMonth(DateRegistered).ToString(),
            persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(DateRegistered).ToString()});
    }
```

Then I used `modelItem.PersianDate` in view like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersianDate)
```

and I think is's a suitable way to use any other methods to convert other properties as well.